# Como rotar imagen con PHP

Tags: php

muy buenos días. Hay alguna forma para rotar la imagen con PHP? para que con un botón pueda rotar la imagen y esta guarde esos cambios.

En la base de datos yo estoy almacenando solo la ruta/nombre de imagen.jpg

En la carpeta quedan todas las imagenes, el problema es que cuando tomo una foto queda en horizontal así la tome en vertical.

Entonces la idea es poder tener un botón que me permita rotar la imagen y dejarla como la necesite ver.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<img src="<?php echo $datosone['fotobrab']; ?>" width="300px"/>
```

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya has probado el uso de `imagerotate()` ?? -> https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imagerotate.php

Comment: Si no lo has hecho, trata de probarlo primero, luego actualiza el post.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: y nunca conto...

Comment: Hola Excorpion si me funciono el link que me enviaste, muchas gracias.